# How to add Talipp Indicators in MySQL database

Tags: python, sql, mysql

I am utilizing the 'Talipp' library in Python to compute diverse moving averages, such as ALMA, DEMA, EMA, HMA, KAMA, SMA, SMMA, T3, TEMA, WMA, and ZLEMA. Subsequently, I aim to store these calculated values in a MySQL database with columns 'name', 'date', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', and 'volume'. However, I am encountering an error during this process. I am unable to connect Python with SQL .

Here is my code

```py
from talipp.ohlcv import OHLCV
from talipp.indicators import ALMA, DEMA, EMA, HMA, KAMA, SMA, SMMA, T3, TEMA, WMA, ZLEMA
import pymysql
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# MySQL connection details
host = 'localhost'
user = 'root'
password = 'Namit@99'
database = 'new_minute'

# Function to update data in the database
def update_database():
    # Create a SQLAlchemy engine
    engine = create_engine(f'mysql+pymysql://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{database}')

    # Connect to the MySQL database
    conn = pymysql.connect(host=host, user=user, password=password, database=database)

    # Write SQL query to fetch data
    query = 'SELECT * FROM minute'

    # Read the SQL query result into a DataFrame using the engine
    price = pd.read_sql(query, engine)

    # Create OHLCV data
    ohlcv_data = OHLCV(
        price['open'].tolist(),
        price['high'].tolist(),
        price['low'].tolist(),
        price['close'].tolist(),
        price['volume'].tolist()
    )

    # Calculate indicator values
    alma_period = 1
    alma_offset = 0.85
    alma_sigma = 6
    alma_values = ALMA(period=alma_period, offset=alma_offset, sigma=alma_sigma,
    input_values=ohlcv_data.close)

    dema_period = 1
    dema_values = DEMA(period=dema_period, input_values=ohlcv_data.close)

    ema_period = 1
    ema_values = EMA(period=ema_period, input_values=ohlcv_data.close)

    hma_period = 2
    hma_values = HMA(period=hma_period, input_values=ohlcv_data.close)

    kama_period = 4
    fast_period = 2
    slow_period = 30
    kama_values = KAMA(period=kama_period, fast_ema_constant_period=fast_period,                              
    slow_ema_constant_period=slow_period, input_values=ohlcv_data.close)

    sma_period = 1
    sma_values = SMA(period=sma_period, input_values=ohlcv_data.close)

    smma_period = 1
    smma_values = SMMA(period=smma_period, input_values=ohlcv_data.close)

    t3_period = 1
    t3_factor = 0.7
    t3_values = T3(period=t3_period, factor=t3_factor, input_values=ohlcv_data.close)

    tema_period = 1
    tema_values = TEMA(period=tema_period, input_values=ohlcv_data.close)

    wma_period = 1
    wma_values = WMA(period=wma_period, input_values=ohlcv_data.close)

    zlema_period = 1
    zlema_values = ZLEMA(period=zlema_period, input_values=ohlcv_data.close)

    # Store the calculated indicator values in the database
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    for index, row in price.iterrows():
        # Update the row in the database table
        cursor.execute('''
            UPDATE minute
            SET alma=%s, dema=%s, ema=%s, hma=%s, kama=%s, sma=%s, smma=%s, t3=%s, tema=%s, wma=%s,      
            zlema=%s
            WHERE id=%s
        ''', (alma_values[index], dema_values[index], ema_values[index], hma_values[index],                                                                                                                                                                                                               kama_values[index], sma_values[index], smma_values[index], t3_values[index], wma_values[index], zlema_values[index], row['id'])
    
         
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    update_database()
```

Error which I am facing

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Namit Dubey\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 644, in connect
    sock = socket.create_connection(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\socket.py", line 828, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\socket.py", line 963, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11003] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Namit Dubey\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 145, in __init__
    self._dbapi_connection = engine.raw_connection()
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Namit Dubey\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3292, in raw_connection
    return self.pool.connect()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Namit Dubey\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 452, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Namit Dubey\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 1269, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Namit Dubey\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 716, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Namit Dubey\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 169, in _do_get
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "C:\Users\Namit Dubey\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 146, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File "C:\Users\Namit Dubey\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 167, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Namit Dubey\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 393, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Namit Dubey\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 678, in __init__
    self.__connect()
  File "C:\Users\Namit Dubey\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 902, in __connect
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "C:\Users\Namit Dubey\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 146, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File "C:\Users\Namit Dubey\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 898, in __connect
    self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Namit Dubey\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\create.py", line 637, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Namit Dubey\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 616, in connect
    return self.loaded_dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Namit Dubey\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 358, in __init__
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Namit Dubey\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 711, in connect
    raise exc
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '99@localhost' ([Errno 11003] getaddrinfo failed)")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Namit Dubey\Desktop\Talipp\Taldb.py", line 91, in <module>
    update_database()
  File "c:\Users\Namit Dubey\Desktop\Talipp\Taldb.py", line 25, in update_database
    price = pd.read_sql(query, engine)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Namit Dubey\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 652, in read_sql
    with pandasSQL_builder(con) as pandas_sql:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Namit Dubey\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 851, in pandasSQL_builder
    return SQLDatabase(con, schema, need_transaction)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Namit Dubey\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1576, in __init__
    con = self.exit_stack.enter_context(con.connect())
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Namit Dubey\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3268, in connect
    return self._connection_cls(self)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Namit Dubey\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 147, in __init__
    Connection._handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection(
  File "C:\Users\Namit Dubey\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2430, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
    raise sqlalchemy_exception.with_traceback(exc_info[2]) from e
  File "C:\Users\Namit Dubey\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 145, in __init__
    self._dbapi_connection = engine.raw_connection()
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Namit Dubey\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3292, in raw_connection
    return self.pool.connect()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Namit Dubey\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 452, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Namit Dubey\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 1269, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Namit Dubey\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 716, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Namit Dubey\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 169, in _do_get
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "C:\Users\Namit Dubey\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 146, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File "C:\Users\Namit Dubey\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 167, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Namit Dubey\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 393, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Namit Dubey\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 678, in __init__
    self.__connect()
  File "C:\Users\Namit Dubey\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 902, in __connect
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "C:\Users\Namit Dubey\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 146, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File "C:\Users\Namit Dubey\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 898, in __connect
    self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Namit Dubey\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\create.py", line 637, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Namit Dubey\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 616, in connect
    return self.loaded_dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Namit Dubey\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 358, in __init__
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Namit Dubey\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 711, in connect
    raise exc sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '99@localhost' ([Errno 11003] getaddrinfo failed)")
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)
```

Comment: Yes there is '@' in password

Comment: I know I am making some mistake, can you correct it ?

Comment: The linked duplicates show how you can get around this (the first duplicate is better style)